# why constructor is not called for static objects created inside a class?

Tags: object, constructor, static

```
      #include<iostream>

      class A
      {
        public:
        int x;
        A()
         {
            x=4;
            std::cout<<"inside A constructor"<<std::endl;
      }
      void function()
      {
        std::cout<<"inside function"<<x<<std::endl;
      }

      };

      class B
      {
         public:
         B()
         {
          std::cout<<"inside b constructor"<<std::endl;
          obj.function();

         }
         private:
         static A obj;
         };
         B b;
         A B::obj;

        int main()
         {

          }
```

In the above code obj.function(); is called for the first time it knows that obj is a member of class A,since initialization of static objects done during the compile time itself,but why not the constructor is called.
The constructor is called only after control hits the line A B::obj;
if i declare the static A obj; outside class B then the constructor is called.
why the behavior is different for both?

Answer (score 0):

B b;
when the above line executes,the constructor of B is called first.
so "inside b constructor" is printed first.

Then when control reaches obj.function(); the obj is already initialized by the
compiler since it is a static type of object.
so obj.function() is called without any problem and "inside function" is printed.

Now the control reaches A B::obj; definition of static object.
so constructor of A is called and "inside A constructor" is printed.

note:
only when the definition of static object is called the constructor is used.
so only we donot see constructor of A when static A obj; is declared inside the class B.

Another question may arise why declaration is only made for static variables inside a class and definition needs to be called explicitly outside class?

The answer is the definition of class can be made inside a header file and this header file can be included in multiple *.cpp files.
so,If the definition is also present inside the class then the static variable will have multiple definitions which will cause erroe.

Inorder to avoid the above the definition for static members outside a class is made exclusively.